# Google Font wont dequeue

Tags: fonts

I'm having an issue getting one of the google fonts to dequeue on my site `https://subscriptionboxes.co.nz`

I've done all the reading, and I can see it needs to be dequeued after its been called, but before its been printed, but I cant figure out how to find that info?
I also cant work out which plugin is making the call?

This is the code I have put in my child `functions.php`

```php
function remove_google_fonts_stylesheet() { 
    wp_dequeue_style( 'googleFontsOpenSans' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'google-fonts-1' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_google_fonts_stylesheet', 12 );
```

It worked great for the "opensans" font, but the "google-fonts-1" which is actually roboto, won't seem to go away no matter what changes I make.

Comment: You can always increase the priority of the action, third argument. To better understand how a equeue is called I would suggest using [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), the best plugin while developing in WordPress, among other things it can give you all handles of style/css and priority.

Comment: There are styles that are registered, for that you would need to use [wp_deregister_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_style/), just add both, if changing the priority didn't help and you are sure that you have the correct handle.

Comment: Thanks Buttered, ive installed query monitor, but i still cant work out how to find the culprit, or the priority.

Yeah i forgot to mention i tried about 20 different priorities, from 1 to 10 to 999.
I also tried the deregister thing ( i think i did it properly) and it made no change either.

Im hoping someone can take 5 mins out of thier day to find this info for me, as its probably super easy for someone who knows.

Thanks for your time mate

Comment: all good i figured it out, a known issue here with elementor
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/4075

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the font will be registered after wp_enqueue_scripts that you set is executed. To be sure, it is better to test the following code once:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_google_fonts_stylesheet', 999999);
```